# How to draw a barplot with columns of circle instead of regular bar in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I've been trying to change the shape of column in barplot. The desired result looks something like this

[image]

Could you please tell me where to set column shape in ggplot or other barplot function?

Comment: Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62592214/changing-the-shape-of-bars-in-ggplot2-bar-plot) to see if that could be useful.

Comment: Or maybe something like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25014492/geom-bar-pictograms-how-to

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! I found this plot can be easily achieved using excel by swaping the bar with an image(shape) and then enabling stack in the fill menu.